# Is this a bug in Thunderbird filtering?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I'm trying to create a Thunderbird filter that moves all emails from a certain coworker addressed only to me to a special folder and I can't figure out how to get it to work.

The first thing I tried is the following, which is the most straightforward, I guess:
[image]

This does not behave as expected in that messages with several people in the `to` field will also be moved by this filter.

I then tried another variant:
[image]

But again no luck. The `cc` is filtered correctly, not so the `to`. Messages with more than one recipient, despite having a ',' in the `to` field get moved as before.

I'm a little bit confused by this. Is there something obvious I'm missing or is the Thunderbird filtering just bugged? Because these filters clearly don't behave is I would expect them to behave.

I'm running 45.4.0 if that helps and I only have very restricted rights as this is on an institute machine, so I can't install extensions.

Comment: My bet would be that the "," won't _actually_ be in the field, it's just a visual separator in the UI, so the filter can't filter on it.

Comment: Hm, that's a good point. Do you have any idea what one could filter for then?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I can filter for ',' in the 'to' field, actually. It's only the 'doesn't contain ,' which does not work for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thunderbird does not natively support this, but there's a workaround that you can use to get it to work.

First go to menu *Extra* > *Addressbook*

Go to menu *File* > *New* > *Addressbook*

Call the new addressbook: `Only Me`

In this new addressbook add one contact and make sure it has your email adress. If you have several adresses, you can add more contacts.

Now, from the rule, 
`To` `Is not in my addressbook` `Only Me`

And From as you already had.

As action you select: Stop processing rules.

A second action would be set: Is from your co-worker, and CC empty. The action would be the desired action.

Make sure these rules are the last ones to be executed, otherwise those after will not execute.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work. Messages with several recipients are still filtered by it. Do you have any other idea? I'm really stumped.

Comment: What if you use: Is not in my addressbook -> stop processing rules. And with the next rule, you do the action for every message, and order your rules so that this is executed last?

Comment: Thanks, great idea! What I do now is I apply two filters: 1) if from is coworker and to is not in my addressbook -> stop filter execution 2) if from is coworker and 'cc' is empty, move message to desired folder. This does what I want it to do, however I feel it's far more complicated that necessary. Do you want to update your answer, or shall I edit it?

Comment: I've updated my answer, reflecting the changes.